# Why do the sisters communicate in English?

Tags: monsters-of-krakow

In the series *Monsters of Kraków*, two of the members of the nine-person group with unusual abilities are the sisters Hania and Basia. They are given to speaking quite idiomatic, seemingly largely American-accented English on occasion, even though the rest of the people essentially exclusively speak Polish (minus the odd bit of French when Professor Zawadzki is talking to his foreign contact). They do this even when talking to the other, presumably Polish-speaking members of the group, and even when communication is critical (e.g. communicating positions and orders during a mission).

What is this meant to indicate about their characters? Is it meant to suggest that they grew up in the USA (or are in fact American students studying in Poland)? Are they in an [English medical program](https://medschool.uj.edu.pl/medical-education/academic-program/) and trying to keep in practice? Is it meant to illustrate some facet of their powers (e.g., that they can learn languages easily due to being able to read minds or something of the sort)?